# Is there anything interesting about primes $p$ such that average of primes $<= p$ is a whole number?

Tags: number-theory

I have been playing around with a program I wrote implementing the sieve of Eratosthenes, and I stumbled across some prime numbers that, when you average them with all the primes less than or equal to them, you get an integer. I was wondering if these are of any interest in modern research, or in any part of mathematics? Does anyone know anything about such primes?

Here are the first eight:

83

241

6599

126551

1544479

4864121

60686737

991184221

Comment: See the relevant [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A171399) entry.